# Meaning of this sentence?

Tags: meaning, quotations

"The man who does not shrink from self-crucifixion can never fail to accomplish the task upon which his heart is set."

context:quote

"Men are anxious to improve their circumstances, but are unwilling to improve themselves. They therefore remain bound. The man who does not shrink from self-crucifixion can never fail to accomplish the object upon which his heart is set. This is as true of earthly as of heavenly things. Even the man whose sole object is to acquire wealth must be prepared to make great personal sacrifices before he can accomplish his object; and how much more so he who would realize a strong and well-poised life? ." -James Allen

Comment: What is the context? Please [edit] your question

Answer (score 1):

From context the meaning of the sentence is fairly clear.

> The man who does not shrink from self-crucifixion can never fail to accomplish the task upon which his heart is set.

could be worded in more simple English:

> The man who does not hide from pain or difficulties will complete the task which he desires to.